# Changing names of Guest Additions for Vbox

Tags: configuration, virtualbox, reverse-engineering, virtualbox-guest-additions

Is it possible to rename the guest additions components within virtual-box to anything different?

Some software behaves differently if it finds guest additions components on a machine, but they usually do it by doing string comparison against processes and internal components, so I was thinking that if I could just rename the components then I could avoid the trouble of replicating guest addition functionality manually.

It might not be possible if guest additions expects it's own components to be named correctly if it searches for them in the same way that .dll files get searched for, but I thought it might be worth a shot anyhow.

Comment: and how will you hide 20 year old hardware? I mean chipset PIIX3 and other outdated things which can be found in museums only?

Comment: http://byte-atlas.blogspot.com/2017/02/hardening-vbox-win7x64.html

Comment: I populate the hardware from a different machine using the script from this tutorial.